# ssh-dss on heroku-20 stack

Tags: heroku, ssh

On upgrading my Ruby on Rails app from the heroku-16 to heroku-20 stack, I'm no longer able to connect to a certain SFTP server:

```
could not settle on host_key algorithm
Server host_key preferences: ssh-dss
Client host_key preferences: ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-rsa
```

It appears they have removed support for ssh-dss this in the current stack. According to https://www.openssh.com/legacy.html it can be enabled by modifying /.ssh/config file with '

```
Host somehost.example.org
    HostKeyAlgorithms +ssh-dss
```

though I don't know how or if it's possible to modify this on Heroku.

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: I am having a similar issue. Do you use Net::SSH or Net:SFTP?

Comment: Using Net::SFTP to make the connection, though the project has both gems installed

Answer (score 0):

I was able to re-enable DSS by adding `append_all_supported_algorithms: true` as a parameter to the `Net::SFTP.start` call. According to the net-ssh [documentation](https://github.com/net-ssh/net-ssh), this will work until version 7 of the gem which removes DSS support entirely.